# Changing InnoDB table format to dynamic

Tags: innodb, table

I run a forum, and this new warning pops up in the admin area:

> You have one or more InnoDB tables that are using the `Compact` row
> format. This may limit the amount of data that can be stored within
> the table. We recommend changing it to 'Dynamic'. If you are not sure
> how to do this, you should contact your hosting provider or system
> administrator for assistance.

Some things I have learned while researching this: I may need to change to file_format=Barracuda. I'm not sure how. But I did find the following code that seems to be closely what I am looking for: (it doesn't work for me)

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( "ALTER TABLE `", table_schema, "`.`", table_name, "` ROW_FORMAT =DYNAMIC ;" ) 
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE
    table_schema IN ( 'Name database' );
```

from https://www.programmersought.com/article/30597194824/

It seems like such a simple thing to do, but then again, SQL isn't my forte.

Comment: can you provide a small create table to  test this?

Comment: How many billion rows (or terabytes) will you have in the table?  I am wondering whether you are trying to solve a non-existent problem.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table that is getting that warning; maybe it has to do with column widths.

Comment: Thank you but I did get it sorted. It was solved by brute force, and about 5 hours of tinkering. Ended up editing mysql config files and restarting the service. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

When you alter the row_format thr file format will be automatically set

> The way to modify the file format is to re-create the table and its indexes. The easiest way to recreate a table and its indexes is to use the following command on each table that you want to modify:

```
ALTER TABLE t ROW_FORMAT=format_name;
```

**Please make a full backup, before trying anything at all**

the following will change all tables in the database testdb, who has not the row_format dynamic

```
SELECT
    @sql :=  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( "ALTER TABLE `", table_schema, "`.`", table_name, "` ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;" ) SEPARATOR " ")
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE
    table_schema = 'testdb'
    AND ROW_FORMAT <> 'Dynamic';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;    
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: It looks like we are about there. Kindly advise.#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `admin_thedix`.`calendar_event_rsvp` ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC; ALTER TABLE' at line 1

Comment: you have to check the manual https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-dynamic-row-format/  seems like you need to change the fileformat as you presumned https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-dynamic-row-format/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I finally got it all sorted.